# How to use getline in spark from hdfs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, file-read

I used `saveAsTextFile("outputPath")` to save file using scala in spark.

I want to read the saved file one by one like `getline` command in c or java from HDFS.

How can I use this?

Is it possible to read the file one by one?